# kill screen session in an expect script

Tags: unix, gnu-screen, expect

I start my screen connection with a spawn command within an expect script:
spawn screen /dev/...

But I don't know how I can kill the screen when the script is finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run screen, use the `-S` option to give it a unique session name. Then, you can send it commands with the `-X` option. The `quit` command will kill the screen, like so:

```
$ screen -S myscreen -d -m
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        2651.myscreen (09/06/2012 04:56:06 PM)        (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-username.
$ screen -S myscreen -X quit
$ screen -ls
No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-username.
```